# PHP CentOS - Couchbase Connection failure

Tags: php, couchbase, centos6

I have a problem connecting to the `Couchbase` database on the server. I installed `Couchbase`  and it's running fine on the server. I can access it via the console, and also through the web application hosted on my local machine, but when I deploy the site to the server, I get this connection error:

`Failed to connect libcouchbase to the server: Connection failure`

I assume that the problem is with the `libcouchbase` module on the server. I use `Ubuntu` on my local and `CentOS 6` on the server and those are the only parameters that make the platforms differ as far as this issue is concerned.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? Any solutions / guidance?

Comment: could you try to run the same case using cbc (available in libcouchbase2-bin package)? For example: cbc cat -h example.com:8091 -b mybucket foo. Also can you dump the config: curl http://example.com:8091/pools/default/buckets/mybucket and make sure that node addresses are accessible

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried command you gave me and it worked just fine. However, I don't really understand what you mean by "using curl" on your last sentence.

Comment: the curl will dump the cluster configuration to your terminal, and it will have a list of node endpoints. it is possible to configure cluster in the way when it will render internal IP addesses there (unlike public). And in this case the client will report that it has been connected to cluster successfully, but cannot do any data IO. I was asking about more diagnostic output

Comment: I see. I will try that and get back to you. Thank you so much.